# TensorFlow boolean indexing

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

Let's go straight, currently, I want to index a tensor and change the non-zero term to -1 and zero term to 1. But I don't know how to do it in TensorFlow.

Here is my code:

```
y_[y_ != 0].assign(-1)
y_[y_ == 0].assign(1)
```

The reason is TensorFlow doesn't seem to support boolean indexing. How can I fix it?

Btw, it seems `boolean_mask` doesn't work for me, because I don't want to return a slice of y_, I just want y_ to change its values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **tf.cond ()**, for the conditional assignment. I have given an example code below,

```
import tensorflow as tf

x_= tf.Variable(5) #non-zero variable
y_= tf.Variable(0) #variable euqals to 0

y_ =tf.cond(tf.equal(y_,0),lambda :y_.assign(1),lambda :y_.assign(-1)) #assign 1 if variable equals to zero else -1
x_ =tf.cond(tf.equal(x_,0),lambda :x_.assign(1),lambda :x_.assign(-1)) #assign 1 if variable equals to zero else -1

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

with sess.as_default():
   print(y_.eval()) #prints 1
   print(x_.eval()) #prints -1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! This can do excellent job for rank 0 case! However, in my case, since y_ is in the flow of CNN, its shape is actually rank1 (in my case, it's (?,)) before I really run the graph. Now the output is `ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for 'cond/Switch' (op: 'Switch') with input shapes: [?], [?].`, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Hi, Nipun! I think I just solved this problem by using `tf.where`, still, thanks for your effort!

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry I didn't make it clear! Still thanks for your help!